# Is DoDirectPayment method for CreditCard of PayPal API only supports USD?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have implemented `DoDirectPayment` method for CreditCard of PayPal API using PHP NVP.
While doing payment, if I use USD currency then only it works and in response it displayed `ACK=Success`, `PAYMENTSTATUS:Completed`.

But if I do payment using any other currency (not USD), then it failed to do payment and in response I am getting,

```
**ACK=Success, 
PAYMENTSTATUS:  Pending
PENDINGREASON:  multicurrency**
```

Why this happens? Let me know as soon as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get correlation id back in response?

Comment: Yes i am getting correlation id. Now what to do?

Comment: provide me if you could , else raise ticket at www.paypal.com/mts

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to change currency related settings in your PayPal account . You can go to this url :

For Sandbox :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-pref&rc2_eligible=yes

For Live :

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-pref&rc2_eligible=yes

Here you will tell the PayPal what action needs to be taken when a Payment other than USD comes in your account .

*Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold:*

**Yes, accept and convert them to U.S. Dollars.**

**No, deny the payments**

**Ask Me, decide accepting or denying each individual payment**